# Message sending in vk with python requests without vkapi

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, vk

I tried to write a code that can log in to vk and write a message to someone, but it doesn't work completely. This code can authorize only. What am I doing wrong?

```
import requests

def msgbot(login, password):
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': '*/*'}

    s=requests.Session()
    request=s.get('https://vk.com/',headers=headers)

    data={'act':'login',
    'role':'al_frame',
    'expire':'',
    'recaptcha':'',
    'captcha_sid':'',
    'captcha_key':'',
    '_origin':'https://vk.com',
    'ip_h':'1156278a4c0c99b955',
    'ig_h':'89e0f10512014ddf94',
    'ul':'',
    'email': login,
    'pass': password}

    data1={'act':'a_send',
    'al':'1',
    'entrypoint':'',
    'gid':'0',
    'guid':'157803940961659',
    'hash':'1578039351_b7a096bfb111bd2d4e',
    'im_v':'3',
    'media':'',
    'msg':'w',
    'random_id':'2002673182',
    'to':'207150714'}

    request=s.get('https://login.vk.com/?act=login', data=data, headers=headers)
    request=s.get('https://vk.com/al_im.php', data=data1, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Please share any errors and more detail about exactly what does not work.

Comment: String 'request=s.get('https://login.vk.com/?act=login', data=data, headers=headers)' must log in to vk and it makes this, string 'request=s.get('https://vk.com/al_im.php', data=data1, headers=headers)' must send a message and it doesn't make this, i don't know why. Sublime text shows that this code has no errors.